# SSAS Tabular Model - Add column to existing table

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2019, ssas-tabular

I am using VS2019 for SSAS Tabular Model development.  Have imported     a table from a CSV.  The source CSV has undergone a change(new column    has been added). When I process my table in VS2019, it gets processed    successfully.  However I am unable to see the new column introduced      in source CSV. I went to Table properties and did a Refresh Preview but was     not able to see the new column. Closed and re-started solution,       re-processed the table but no luck! I remember in VS2017 we used to      add the column by going into table properties and selecting the new      column but things seem to be different in VS2019. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you used Get Data / Power Query to import the CSV.  This unfortunately generates a Power Query **Csv.Document** function call that includes the number of columns when the query was generated. This parameter isn't exposed through the usual Power Query UI.

If you use the Advanced Editor or turn on the Formula Bar (view menu), you will see a parameter like `Columns=10,` was generated, usually in your **Source** step.

It currently seems safe to delete that parameter by editing the code - it will then always pull back all columns presented.  Or if you prefer, you can edit the number of columns, as described in this blog post:
https://prathy.com/2016/08/how-to-add-extra-columns-to-an-existing-power-bi-file-which-using-csv-data-source/